# Does JGit API have all Git commands

Tags: git, jgit, git-remote, git-am

I am trying to port a shell script to Java which contains a few Git commands which I have mostly managed to find in the JGit API. I have not, however, managed to find the remote or am commands, is this because the don't exist or I am just looking in the wrong place for them. If they don't exist is there another way to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready-to run counterpart for `git remote` and `am` in JGit, but it should be possible to implement (a subset of) them with reasonable effort.

Those sub-commands of `git remote` that query or manipulate the config file can be emulated by directly accessing the repository configuration through `Repository.getConfig()`.

To clean stale remote-tracking branches like `git remote prune` does, you can use `LsRemoteCommand` to obtain a list of existing remote branches and remove remotes from the local configuration that do not match that list.

Replacing `git am` might be a little more effort. There is an `ApplyCommand` to apply a patch from a given input stream as well as the low-level `Patch` class to parse diffs. What would be left is to parse the mailbox files and produce a commit from the contained diffs and meta-data (message, author, etc.).