# How can I change URI of a Git (jgit)

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ssh, jgit

I am developing an Eclipse plugin which users can log in through this plugin and use some git repositories (through ssh and with user/password credentials) which are accessed behind the curtains. Users do not know their ssh passwords.

These users have read only access to a git repository. When one of the users logs in on a computer for the first time, the git is pulled on to the local machine. There is no problem so far. When user logs out, for the efficiency I want to keep this local copy on this machine. And my problem starts at this point.

When another user logs in, I retrieve the git object from the local copy and unfortunately (for me), it includes the URI which is set for the first user.

Is there a way to set the URI of a org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git object.

I try the following code with no success. Setting URI thii way throws org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: No value for key remote

This code (without setting URI) works as expected for the same user. And it updates the local copy from remote.

```
Git git = Git.open(new File("PATH" + "/.git"));

git.pull()
  .setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback() {
    @Override
    public void configure( Transport transport ) {
      if( transport instanceof SshTransport ) {
        SshTransport sshTransport = ( SshTransport )transport;
        sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
          @Override
          protected void configure(Host hc, Session session) {
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setPassword("password");
          }
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .setRemote(remoteURI)
  .call();
```

Comment: How much do you know about Git? (not specifically EGit)

Comment: @immibis Some. Any crucial part I am missing?

Comment: Well, a Git repository doesn't just have "a URI" (assuming you don't mean the URI of your copy of the main repository); it can have multiple "remotes".

Comment: When I say URI I am referring something in the form of ssh://<USER_NAME>@<SERVER_IP>:<PATH>/project.git                          Then you say I need to remove old URI and add a new one? By the way two URI is exactly same except the <USER_NAME> part

Comment: first: how would you do it from the Git command line? Second, try to find a way to do that in Java.

Comment: Something like this? git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here

Comment: Looks like jgit does not have a "git remote" command. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225273/does-jgit-api-have-all-git-commands